# Route [news.shownewspublic] not defined

Tags: laravel-8

I want to view some data but I got this error Route [news.shownewspublic] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp - 1.0.2\resources\views\news\indexnewspublic.blade.php)
This is my resources\views\news folder
[image]
This is resources\views\news\indexnewspublic.blade.php

```
@foreach ($news as $news)
  <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{{route('news.shownewspublic'),$news->id}}">
     <img src="/image/{{ $news->image }}" width="100px" class="col-2">
     <div class="col-2" style="color: #1d2124">
     <strong>App Name:- {{ $news->name }}</strong>
     </div>
 </a>
@endforeach
```

This is my NewsController.php

```
public function indexnewspublic()
{
  $news = News::latest()->paginate(5);
  return view('news.indexnewspublic',compact('news'))
     ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
public function shownewspublic(News $news)
{
  return view('news.shownewspublic',compact('news'));
}
```

This is web.php

```
Route::resource('news', NewsController::class);
Route::get('/indexnewspublic', [NewsController::class, 'indexnewspublic']);
Route::get('/shownewspublic', [NewsController::class, 'shownewspublic']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by in indexnewspublic.php
`@foreach ($news as $news) <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{{ url('shownewspublic/' . $news->id) }}"> {{ $news->name }} <img src="/image/{{ $news->image }}" width="100px" class="col-6"> </a> @endforeach`
This is web.php

```
Route::get('indexnewspublic/{id}', [NewsController::class, 'indexnewspublic'])->name('indexnewspublic');
```

This is NewsController.php

```
public function indexnewspublic()
{
$news = News::latest()->paginate(5);
return view('news.indexnewspublic',compact('news'))
  ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```